Sync max Record Task in a service
It's Sync Max Activity Records in one data file task. Which has 2 requirements
1.If activity records is empty or null so no file will be created 2.If activity records is more than 10000 then it's create new file for another activity records means in one file only 10000 records will be stored if 100020 records will come then for 10000 create one file and for 20 create another file
if (total > 0) {
        noOfFiles++;
        try (FileWriter datafile = new FileWriter(dataFileDirectory + "Data_" + jobId + "_" + noOfFiles + "." + fileextension)) {
         datafile.write(records.toString());
         datafile.flush();
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

    private static final int MAX_RECORDS_PER_FILE = 10000;

    public static void writeRecordsToFile(List<String> records) {
        if (records == null || records.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        int totalRecords = records.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < totalRecords; i += MAX_RECORDS_PER_FILE) {
            int end = Math.min(totalRecords, i + MAX_RECORDS_PER_FILE);
            List<String> subList = records.subList(i, end);
            // write [i, end] records to file 
        }
    }

Do you mean this?I hope it will be helpful to you
